# Localstorage not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having troubles with this, for some reason if this is located in the same page `index.html` the localstore var works, but if I move this into my site.js nothing happens

```
var check = "Login as Admin";
  var names = [];
  var a = check;    
  names[0] = a;
  localStorage["names"] = JSON.stringify(names);
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage["names"]);
```

This works

```
var check = "Login as Admin";
  var names = [];
  var a = check;    
  names[0] = a;
  localStorage["names"] = JSON.stringify(names);
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage["names"]);

if(storedNames == "Login as Admin"){
  window.location="events_edit.html";
}
```

Comment: Something to think about: What if the users inspects the source of your page and finds out your admin page?

Comment: thats all i have for now, the site.js will contain only the localstorage var

Comment: `storedNames` is an array. If it contains more than one element, it will never equal to `"Login as Admin"` which is a string.

Comment: Your solution contains two items on the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10): Broken Authentication and Insecure Direct Object References.

Comment: @levi so because it is an array is the reason that don't work, becuase what is weird is that if I have all the js in the same page works fine, but when move part of the code to a different page don't

Comment: @levi That's untrue. Because the condition is coercing the array into a string, it is true in this case. Messy, but true. `["Login as Admin"].toString() == "Login as Admin"`

Comment: @CarlosPerez Are you sure you've included the site.js file in your HTML and that it is loaded before checking `storedNames` in your html file?

Comment: @rgthree My point was, if there is more than one element in the array, it will no longer be casted to a (valid) string, and hence the condition will never evaluate to true.